# Share Database With Other Computer In Network

Tags: php, mysql, networking, phpmyadmin

I have computer server and client, installed xampp v3.2.1 to configure database in server and custom web application in every computer. I can access phpmyadmin and CRUD database from computer client by access ip server (192.168.1.1/phpmyadmin) in browser. But, I can not access database if I use my web application. This is code to connect database :

```
<?php 
$server="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$id_mysql=mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password); 
if (! $id_mysql) 
    die("tak dapat melakukan koneksi ke server MYSQL"); 

$db_latihan = mysql_select_db ("dewata",$id_mysql); 
if (! $db_latihan) 
    die("tidak dapat mengakses db latihan"); 

$host='localhost'; 
$user='root'; 
$pass=''; 
$DataBase='dewata'; 
?>
```

I have tried change $server="localhost" to 192.168.1.1 / 192.168.1.1:80 / 192.168.1.1:3306 but not work.

It always shows error A connection attemp failed because the connected party did not properly respond after period time.

Any idea, tips, solution? Thanks for helping.

Comment: We're not short on vertical space here, please expand that single line of code into something readable.

Comment: Well, is the database exposed to external connections? Are permissions set up to allow external connections? Is the firewall (if present) configured to allow incoming connections?

Comment: your question not clear! , try to locate your project with , 192.168.1.1/your_project

Comment: I can acces 192.168.1.1/dewata from client (dewata is my web application located in server) and CRUD database like normally. But there is case where I have to one special computer that has dewata inside (so I acces it by localhost/dewata not 192.168.1.1/dewata) but it connect database in server.

Comment: Is mysql configured in a away, that it can be access from the outside? There are sttings in its config for that and the user you use needs the privileges to access from outside of localhost.

Comment: I have edited privileges in phpmyadmin > menu Users. But yet, not work. Or may be I must edit from file?

Answer (score 0):

I follow this instruction. And It works like a charm :)

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-mysql-or-phpmyadmin-from-outside